# run the app for first time have this error

Tags: flutter

i am begginer
i try to play an app in android studio but I cant and showed me this error.
can you help me?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.5.0/builder-3.5.0.jar

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: DO you have stable internet connection ? if yes try to run ```flutter doctor``` in the terminal, and in Android studio go to File -> Invalidate caches / Restart

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62114905/10595176